# How can you remove your presence from the Internet?

Tags: privacy, deletion

How can you remove your presence from the Internet?

For example from social networks, from email servers, from forums etc. Problem is how records of you are identified on the internet?

We have well known services such as:

- Facebook
- Twitter
- Youtube
- MySpace
- Stackexchange
- Warez forums

If know I have account on a particular server and if I know password I can log on and start deleting information.

There is a project: http://suicidemachine.org/ but I didn’t find anything more complex.

It is possible identify myself on internet by email, IP ... I don’t think use on this purpose google and type own email to google and search - is very simple.

Does some search engine exist which can find me on internet by my email, IP, nick or ...